# sass syntax error when using placeholder

Tags: sass

I defined a placeholder selector in a .sass file as:

```
.bold,
%bold
  font-weight: bold
  font-weight: 500
```

Then I used extend:

```
.pane-share-of-day
  @extend %bold
```

When the css is generated, I get this error message:
Syntax error: Invalid CSS after ".bold,": expected selector, was "%bold"

I am using Sass version 3.2.5.
Any help please.

Answer (score 0):

Adding these declarations into their own file worked just fine for me. Perhaps you can repost with more of what's going around it?

More importantly, though, is the redundancy of this declaration. The [% placeholder selector](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#placeholders) was introduced so you could have a base class that never actually got output. Here you're defining such a class as being identical to another explicitly output class. In other words, if you already need `.bold`, you don't actually need to add `%bold`.

Comment: There's plenty of times you might want to have both a placeholder and another selector in the same declaration.  There might be other things that apply to the `.bold` class that should not apply to `%bold` declared elsewhere in the file (especially if `.bold` has nested selectors).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.bold, bold
  font-weight: bold
  font-weight: 500
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This compiles but unfortunately it doesn't appear to act as a placeholder so it really doesn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
.bold, %bold
  font-weight: bold
  font-weight: 500

.pane-share-of-day
  @extend %bold
```

You can't put two selectors for the same block on different lines in the `.sass` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.bold, %bold
    font-weight: bold
    font-weight: 500
```

There should be no carriage return / no new line between listed selectors (classes, id's, placeholders)

BTW. you don't need to use placeholder selector to use @extend. You could just do:

```
@extend .bold
```